# Convert string datetime to DateTime type in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to combine date and time to DateTime format. so that I can use it to send local notifications.
I am getting time and date separately from firebase as appointment_date and appointment_time:

[image]

using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < appt_list.length; i++) {
          
            String name = appt_list[i].docName;
            String k = appt_list[i].key;
            Provider.of<NotificationService>(context, listen: false)
                .sheduledNotification(datetime, name, k);
          }
```

and i want to use custom (values stored in firebase for appointments reminder) timedate in local notification function like using 'scheduledNotificationDateTime' variable is doing:

```
Future sheduleddateNotification(DateTime datetime, String name, String key) async {
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5));
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(key,
        'your other channel name', 'your other channel description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    IOSNotificationDetails();
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        0,
        'Reminder Appointment',
        'You have an appointment scheduled with $name at ${(time.hour)}:${(time.minute)}',
        scheduledNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

But I don't know how do I combine my date and time together and use them as one! Please help me out in solving this problem

Comment: Why are you re-parsing `date1` as a string to get hours and minutes? The [`DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) class has [properties](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html#instance-properties) that allow you to get those as `int` directly.

Comment: that's because I want to get time before 5 minutes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the string parsing isn't necessary to create `time`. All you need is `var time = Time(date1.hour, date1.minute, 0)`. Although, you don't ever actually use the `time` variable, so either that isn't your full code, or you should delete the unused parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
final String dateTimeString = appointment_date + " " + appointment_time;
final DateFormat format = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
print (format.parse(dateTimeString));
```

Comment: how can I convert this DateFormat to DateTime, since I want to pass DateTime format to schedule notification function?

Comment: @NabiaSalman The [`parse()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat/parse.html) method returns a `DateTime` object.